# master password for user login debugging ubuntu

Tags: server, password, administration

I manage a small cluster. The users call me for problems in vnc or xrdp login. I want to be able to enter to their user direct from xrdp and see the issues.
I need a master password that i can enter any user with all its graphics, credentials and so on.
is there anything like this?

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you and your users using? The root user is disabled by default in Ubuntu and many other distros.